# Ionic 3 media capture plugin not working in iOS

Tags: ios, ionic-framework

Ionic 3  media capture plugin not working in iOS anymore. Anyone can help me?
It's always showing `error code 2`. Working fine in Android but not working on any iOS.

Comment: Can you share some details about the issue? It's really hard to get about the issue by the description  you have provided.

Comment: Add this code in info.plist; `<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>...Comment...</string>`

Comment: or what to use, you must call it and add the key and string to here

Comment: I added before <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key> but not working .
I used ionic ionic media capture plugin, which working fine in android but not working iOS. When I tried to open camera with iOS device it's always going out from app.

Comment: this.mediaCapture.captureVideo({limit:1, duration:600}).then(
          (data: MediaFile[]) => { 
            this.imageURI = data[0].fullPath;
            this.uploadFile();
           // alert(data[0]); 
           }

Comment: I used above code for  ionic media capture plugin. 
So, can you please help me for open camera or working  ionic media capture plugin in iOS